# Install and run frama-C in Windows 7

Tags: frama-c

I have tried to run the Frama-C on windows 7, but it didn't work.

I have read all the tips and comments you wrote here, but still not working.

Can someone explain the installation process is a clear and simple way, and I will grateful?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest install for Windows 7 is to use the Windows binary installer for the Boron release (http://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-Boron-20100401.exe). If you do install this version, you will still need to install the gcc-preprocessor in order for frama-c to build your source code.

Newer releases (i.e., Sodium) require you to build from the source code distribution, which means you will need to install several prerequisites as listed in the install instructions:

- GNU make version >= 3.81
- Objective Caml >= 3.12.1 (except 4.02.0);
- a C compiler with standard C and POSIX headers and libraries

The Frama-C GUI also requires:

- Gtk (>= 2.4)
- GtkSourceView 2.x
- GnomeCanvas 2.x
- LablGtk >= 2.14.0 (and >= 2.18.2 if you use OCaml >= 4.02.1)

If you need to build from source, please comment and I will give you the steps to complete that.

Comment: Just an update: newer releases can be compiled directly by OPAM with [OCaml for Windows](https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/). Since Boron is a very old and unsupported release, using OPAM is currently the recommended way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

fdopen's [OCaml for Windows](https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/) allows installing OPAM with a special repository.

Once you have it, installing Frama-C requires only a few steps:

```
# install depext, for external dependencies
opam install depext
# help Cygwin installing dependencies
opam install depext-cygwinports
# install Frama-C dependencies
opam depext frama-c
# install Frama-C itself
opam install frama-c
```

[Frama-C on Windows](https://bts.frama-c.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=mantis:frama-c:compiling_from_source&#compiling_under_windows_cygwin_mingw) installation instructions are periodically updated on Frama-C's wiki.